# In Google Playstore search app is not visible

Tags: android

The App was published successfully.It's showing in Google PlayStore app search in the devices.
It's showing me a warning sign after my app name.[image]

Comment: As stated in the message, it will take a while to show.

Answer (score 1):

As previously said, you need to wait.  The app will be on the store even before it is searchable.  The process takes a few hours for everything to update. [Within a few hours, your apps will become available to users and your product page will appear in Google Play for browsing, searching, or linking from your promotional campaigns.](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must wait. When I published my app, I waited 3-4 hours. When you edit your app, you must wait also. Check it tomorrow.